# cv::Exception * swig error? or aruco error?

Tags: c++, python-3.x, ubuntu, swig, aruco

I'm implementing this[[URL]](https://github.com/lvsn/deeptracking)

The following error occurs when the test sensor is run.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_sensor.py", line 96, in <module>
    detector = ArucoDetector(sensor.camera, data["detector_layout_path"])
  File "/home/toshi/deeptracking/deeptracking/detector/detector_aruco.py", line 12, in __init__
    boardconfig = aruco.BoardConfiguration(board_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/aruco.py", line 692, in __init__
    this = _aruco.new_BoardConfiguration(*args)
RuntimeError: <Swig Object of type 'cv::Exception *' at 0x7f3489679c30>
swig/python detected a memory leak of type 'cv::Exception *', no destructor found.
```

I am aware of aruco's swig error.
But I don't understand the meaning of this error.
I can run the python-aruco module[[URL](https://github.com/fehlfarbe/python-aruco/tree/dbc29c5cdf98467cb987c565c62402f05066bb2b)]itself, which is used here.
What is the problem?

**environment**

- ubuntu16.04
- python3.5
- aruco1.3.0

Comment: It's a bug in whatever python module you're using.

Comment: @Flexo Thank you. I will try it in another version.